# jQuery 501 error (Unsupported method ('POST'))

Tags: php, jquery

I learning ajax, and im setting up a simplehttpserver in a working directory to run some files in the browser. Now what happens is that when I run my html file, that looks like the following:

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>playground</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>Save</h1>
    <form action="#">
      <textarea name="content" id="content" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
      <p><button type="submit">Save</button></p>
    </form>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    (function($) {

      $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
        $.post('save.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        });
        e.preventDefault();
      });

    })(jQuery);
    </script>

    </body>
  </html>
```

and the 'save.php' is simply this:

```
<?php
    $_POST['content'];
?>
```

Then the browser gives me the error:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/save.php 501 (Unsupported method ('POST')) in jquery.min.js:4
```

I dont get it why should the post method not be supported?

Comment: are you sure, Bcoz your code working fine, i am not sure, try with some other system FF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PSRs answer might work, but what i did was simply stop running the simple app on the simpleHTTPServer and moved it to a mamp server, that supported php better...

Answer (score 1):

send

headers **Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Methods and Access-Control-Allow-Headers**

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470414/strange-jquery-error-code-501-message-unsupported-method-options)

Comment: currently I have a Python script that sends headers, how can I make it send all those?

So far I have `self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')` does this mean I need to have `self.send_header('<one of those headers you suggested>')` for each header you suggested, on separate lines in my script?

Desperate thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use php solution for simple server rather than the python one:

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

If you don't have php installed, run that first:

```
sudo apt install php7.2-cli
```

Answer (score -3):

transfer `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to `<head>` tag