# python server POST .json 501 Unsupported method ('POST')

Tags: python, jquery, json

server.py

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class Server(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.path = '/index.html'
        try:
            file_to_open = open(self.path[1:]).read()
            self.send_response(200)
        except:
            file_to_open = "File not found"
            self.send_response(404)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes(file_to_open, 'utf-8'))


httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 80), Server)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

This python server is pretty simple.

.js

```
$.post( "t.json", array);
```

When I am trying to post to .json file I am getting the following error.

```
POST http://localhost/t.json 501 (Unsupported method ('POST'))
```

I have already read:

- [POST JSON data to file return 501 Unsupported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27610184/post-json-data-to-file-return-501-unsupported)
- [jQuery 501 error (Unsupported method ('POST'))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876926/jquery-501-error-unsupported-method-post)
- [How can I create a web service endpoint for a locally served JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064533/how-can-i-create-a-web-service-endpoint-for-a-locally-served-json-file)

None of them have been solved by using python